# Excel Power automate when any changes or additions

Tags: excel, sharepoint, powerapps, power-automate

I really cant find how to automate this using power

1. I have an excel file which contains a lot of rows
2. The table has columns at row 1 filtered
3. There are two columns C and D - i am interested if they are either "X" OR "Y"
4. I need to get a notification if there are any modifications on the rows for the above criteria alone. All others should be ignored and no notification
5. I also should get a notification if there is a new row with criteria mentioned in point 3.

Comment: Hi and welcome to S.O. Please note this is not a free code writing service. That said, if you can show us what you have tried and explain what the problem you have is, we'd be happy to take a look and help you find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel and PowerAutomate are not what you are looking for. This either requires a proper database, or something like a VBA macro to run your logics on every action.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a work-around to trigger a flow whenever an Excel row is created, modified, or deleted. It also gives the records for each row that changed, so you could check if any fit your criteria & run the rest of your actions based on that.
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Cookbook/When-an-Excel-row-is-created-modified-or-deleted-workaround/td-p/2264670